# Parsing a timestamp based PHP std class obkect

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I have a PHP standard class object converted from json_decode of a REST call on an API which looks like :

```
Array
(
    [1437688713] => stdClass Object
        (
            [handle] => Keep it logically awesome.
            [id] => 377748
            [ping] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://api.me.com
                    [id] => 377748
                    [name] => web
                    [active] => 1
                    [events] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => data_new
                            [1] => data_old
                        )
```

So far i had no issues in parsing any of the PHP objects. However this one is failing because i can not access the nested object elements using a key since 1437688713 is not assigned to a key and accessing an object is failing if i try to do this:

```
$object->1437688713->handle
```

Is there a way to access these elements ?

Update: one more thing, i would never know this value (1437688713) in advance. Just like a key. All i get is a stdclass object which i have to parse.

Comment: `$object[1437688713]->handle` ?

Comment: one more thing, i would never know this value in advance. Just like a key.

Comment: @Rizier123 its not abt array, its abt the stdclass object inside array

Comment: @viral same thing, i dont know what value is going to be there. Otherise it could always be hard coded

Comment: @CodeMonkey but you always want to access the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer part of your data is an array, not an object. Try:

```
$array['1437688713']->handle;
```

or if you don't know the key, you can iterate over the array (handy if it may contain multiple objects too):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $object) { 
  echo $key; // outputs: 1437688713
  echo $object->handle; // outputs: Keep it logically awesome.
}
```

Comment: Totally understand, but what i am trying to do here is to get something inside the iobject

Comment: this looks a cleaner and better solution than the reset object.

Answer (score 1):

Get the first item from `$object` array

```
$first_key = key($object);
```

Use it with your response array,

```
$object[$first_key]->handle;
```

---

Or, the first element of array

```
$first_pair = reset($object)->handle;
```